# Calling C++ dll from python

Tags: python, c++, struct, dll, char

I have a created dll library in c++ and exported it as c type dll. The library header is this:
**library.h**

```cpp
struct Surface
{
    char surfReq[10];
};

struct GeneralData
{
    Surface surface;
    char weight[10];
};

struct Output
{
    GeneralData generalData;
    char message[10];
};
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Calculation(Output &output);
```

**library.cpp**

```cpp
int Calculation(Output &output)
{
  strcpy_s(output.message, 10, "message");
  strcpy_s(output.generalData.weight, 10, "weight");
  strcpy_s(output.generalData.surface.surfReq, 10, "surfReq");
  return 0;
}
```

Now I have this Python script:

```py
#! python3-32
from ctypes import *
import sys, os.path

class StructSurface(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("surfReq", c_char_p)]

class StructGeneralData(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("surface", StructSurface),
                ("weight", c_char_p)]

class OutData(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("generalData", StructGeneralData),
                ("message", c_char_p)]

my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
path = os.path.join(my_path, "../../../libs/Python.dll")

testDll = cdll.LoadLibrary(path)

surfReq = (b''*10)
structSurface = StructSurface(surfReq)

weight = (b''*10)
structGeneralData = StructGeneralData(structSurface, weight)

message = (b''*10)
outData = OutData(structGeneralData, message) 

testDll.restyp = c_int
testDll.argtypes = [byref(outData)]
testDll.Calculation(outData)
print(outData.message)
print(outData.generalData.weight)
print(outData.generalData.surface.surfReq)
```

When I print the fields from outData I get the same results in all of them:

> b'surfReq'
>
> b'surfReq'
>
> b'surfReq'

Can you please tell me how to specify the char arrays/fields so I get the correct result. I am only allowed to change the python script.
I called this library from C# with no problems.

Comment: Include output as properly formatted text in the question, not as external link or image.

Comment: What is "testDll.Skuska" in the Python code? One error is that the C++ structs contain fixed length char arrays while corresponding ctypes structs have char pointers instead.

Comment: I changed `testDll.Skuska` to `testDll.Calculation` (typo).

Comment: I have tried different ctypes. When I try `c_char * 10` (initialization is the same) I get an Error: _"Exception thrown at 0x78AFEE3F (ucrtbased.dll) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014."_ I have also tried `c_byte * 10` (without initialization) and got the same Access violation. Also when I step into the **library.cpp** it says that the output parameter passed by reference is `<struct at NULL>`

Comment: The "byref" should only be used in calls and not as type (interesting that ctypes accepts this). Therefore argtypes should be [POINTER(OutData)] and the actual call parameter of Calculation should be byref(outData).

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you that fixed it! It was weird to me that the byref() want an instance in the argtypes instead of Type. I posted the answer and I want to give some credit/reputation to you. How can I do that? (first time posting a question here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the python ctypes to `c_char * 10`:

```py
class StructSurface(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("surfReq", c_char * 10)]

class StructGeneralData(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("surface", StructSurface),
                ("weight", c_char * 10)]

class OutData(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("generalData", StructGeneralData),
                ("message", c_char * 10)]
```

And changed the argtypes and actual call to

```py
testDll.argtypes = [POINTER(OutData)]
testDll.Calculation(byref(outData))
```